# Modals overlapping on page contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having issues displaying modals properly on my page without them overlapping on contents of the page. I tried severals tweaks but no luck. Kindly help me out. Thanks

You can try viewing  this on the live website using Chrome or Mozilla browser.

[Click here to view website](http://crewresolution.com/public/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
<div class="w3-container">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Read More...</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" 
        class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h3>MESSAGE </h3>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
-
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p>MESSAGE</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              
              <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <div class="box-service">
                  <div class="ic-service text-center">
                    <i class="ti-comment-alt"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3 class="text-uppercase color-dark title-service text-center">Summary</h3>
                  <p>➢ 40% in local currency (Naira) per month.<br> 
➢ 60% in bit coin per month. <br>
➢ 10% constant referral bonus from all direct down lines.<br>
</p>
                  
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Read More...</button>

  <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" 
        class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h3>SUMMARY</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>➢ 40% in local currency (Naira) per month.<br>
➢ 60% in bit coin per month. <br>
➢ 10% constant referral bonus from all direct down lines.<br>
➢ “Alert FBI Icon” conditions: Raise “Alert FBI” only when there is fake POP. Abuse of this will lead to account blocking permanently.<br>
➢ First time registration bonus once:<br>
N10k - N99k gives bonus of N6k or $20<br>
N100k - N499k gives bonus of N20k or $50<br>
N500k - N1M  gives bonus of N50k or $150<br>
➢ Minimum PH of N10k<br>
➢ Once PH there is an instant matching to pay 10% of your total amount PH as a commitment.<br> The remaining 90% will be matched at least 20 days later.

</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p>SUMMARY</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                  
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">
                <div class="box-service">
                  <div class="ic-service text-center">
                    <i class="ti-gift"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h4 class="text-uppercase color-dark title-service text-center">Additional Benefits</h4>
                  <p>1. Free ticket worth N600k to South Africa for all active members with 100 direct down lines and have PH minimum amount of N500k or $1500 for 4 months.</p>
                   <button onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block'" class="w3-button w3-black">Read More...</button>

  <div id="id03" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <header class="w3-container w3-teal"> 
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'" 
        class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h3>ADDITIONAL BENEFITS</h3>
      </header>
      <div class="w3-container">
        <p>1. Free ticket worth N600k to South Africa for all active members with 100 direct down lines and have PH minimum amount of N500k or $1500 for 4 months.<br>
2.  Free N150k will be given to  active members who have participated for 6 months after registration, and the money is for:<br>
• Skills acquisition program.<br>
• Business as an entrepreneur.<br>
• School fee regarded as scholarship.<br>
No condition on amount PH in No.2<br>
3. An active member within the first 4 months of registration with minimum PH of N500k or $1500 in bit coins in each month is qualified to get a loan of N2M and will be paid back for the next 6 months.<br>
Condition:  All of these will be in batches such as: batch A, B, C, D, E, F etc.  
</p>
      </div>
      <footer class="w3-container w3-teal">
        <p>ADDITIONAL BENEFITS</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed your modal's html into same div which opens that modal. I would suggest to keep all modal popup DIVs in a separate div and place it at the bottom of page before closing of body tag.

Like

```
<div>
    <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    .....
    </div>
    <div id="id02" class="w3-modal">
    .....
    </div>
    <div id="id03" class="w3-modal">
     .....
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your navbar has a z-index of 1000, so you need to make sure your modal is above that.
2. Your modals are at the same level as other divs in your body, deep within the body. You need to move them out to be direct children of the `<body>` element, as stated in Ankush's answer.

Once you do this, you will get the desired effect.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="w3-modal"></div> // <--- Direct child of body
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.w3-modal {
    z-index: 1001; // <--- At least 1001, navbar z-index is 1000.
}
```